# Posting to controller using JQuery drop-down box in Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following HTML dropdown box on the **index** view of the **Search** controller. I want to update the view based upon the dropbox selection. I need to pass the selection to the controller somehow.

```
<!-- index.html rendered from Search/Index -->
<select id="search_params" name="search[params]">
   <option value="tacos">tacos</option>
   <option value="pizza">pizza</option>
</select>
```

**Search Controller** code takes params and spits out a message

```
def index
  query = params[:search]
  msg = "Your favorite food is #{query}! OMGWTFBBQ!?!?!?!"

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

This Javascript should somehow post the dropdown box choice to the controller upon selection:

```
$("#search_params").change(function() {
  var state = $('select#search_params :selected').val();
  if(state == "") state="0";
   //Send the selection to the controller Search controller somehow 
   // and then render a new view immediately ?
   //I AM NOT GOOD WITH COMPUTER
})
return false;
});
```

I've looked at dozens of other Rails + JQuery examples, jquery API docs, etc. Can't find an answer to the simple question or I'm just overthinking it.

Anyways, thanks in advance for your help! 
~Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no Ruby/Rails guy but I know jQuery.

I think you want something like

```
$("#search_params").change(function() {
  var state = $('select#search_params :selected').val();
  if(state == "") {
     state="0";
  }
  //Call jQuery AJAX
  $.ajax({
       url:'/path/to/your/controller/action',
       type:'POST',
       data:'search=' + state,
       success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
       },
       error: function() { 
          alert('Stuff went wrong');
       }
    });
  return false;
});
```

Hope this helps, and have a read of the [jQuery AJAX doc page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

I'm not really sure how you're returning your data from the controller there either? Is there a corresponding view that renders `msg`?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout jQuery.ajax() documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You might need to put this at top of application.js (or this might just be a Rails 2.x requirement):

```
// Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
// This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  'beforeSend': function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");
    var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
  }
});
```

I set jQuery.ajax() to expect raw javascript code in the server response.

I have my normal html template render a partial.  Or, all HTML is abstracted to a partial, not a template.

The javascript template will render basically do this:

```
$("div#some_id").html(
  <%= escape_javascript(render(:partial=>'partial_name')) %>
);
```